# Atajo de teclado para generar comentario para funciones en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, atajo

Tengo funciones en c# aspx en visual studio 201 con 15 parámetros aproximadamente

> function x(param1, param2, etc...){}

y quiero agregarles documentación en la parte de arriba para cada parámetro

> /*@param1
>
> *@param2
>
> *etc.
>
> */
>
> function x(param1, param2, etc...){}

He estado agregando esta documentación de forma manual pero algunas veces escribo mal los parámetros o me olvido de alguno o hago alguna otra cosa mal, quisiera generar esa documentación de forma automática, hay alguna forma de hacerlo en visual studio 2015 o tengo que seguir haciéndolo manualmente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aparte de lo que menciona @Pikoh, poner `///`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes utilizar algún complemento como:

MZTOOLS - [link pagina oficial](https://mztools.com/)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con MzTools puedes armar templates.

Complementos para ayudarte a documentar:

- [GhostDoc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeb.GhostDoc)
- [VSdocman](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.VSdocman)
- [Atomineer Pro Documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JasonWilliams.AtomineerProDocumentation)

Parece que el ultimo se acerca mas a lo que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O buscar algún nuget para manejar tu documentación.

Comment: Hola cristina tu generaste el gif???,, como ?

Comment: @Rastalovely si lo generé con eta aplicación: [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/), después lo añadí con el botón de imagen o ctrl + G y listo :-)

Comment: Excelente se ve muy bien, gracias por el aporte. Saludos

Comment: Gracias y para tus futuras respuestas ya tendrás una nueva opción, la de insertar un gif en caso de ser necesario. :-)

Answer (score 7):

En visual Studio, si añades 3 slashes `///` antes de un método, se te genera un texto con el sumario del método y los parámetros de entrada y salida para rellenar, algo asi:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void cmbIpp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

De hecho,utilizando `<summary>` el texto que añadas,asi como la explicación de los parámetros te apareceran en el Intellisense al usar el método, lo cual es muy util.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de hacer lo mismo pero con templates, lo que pasa es que tengo parametros out y ref y en esa documentacion no hay como distinguirlos